# "Couldn't load project" after merging and removing <<<< conflict style markets

Tags: xcode, github

I am relatively new to using Github with XCode, and I recently merged two files. I saw there were conflicts in the `.xcodeproj` file. In the past I have fixed this simply by removing the `<<<`, `====`, and `>>>` lines. In this case, I have done that, fixed the other files with conflicts, but I am still not able to open the Xcode project. I think perhaps I have left in some duplicate information in the `xcodeproj` file, but I have no idea how to figure out what's wrong. How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, when you did it successfully, it probably was because both changes were unique. Probably you added file A to the project in one branch, file B in the other one, merged and got a conflict(but you needed both these changes). With your current situation, the conflict is as simple (if you delete File A in both the branches, and add it back in one branch, your action will mess up the project file)

Do not just remove `<<< === or >>>` without understanding what is happening.

Look for the lines that should remain past merging. Easier for you, will be if you delete the chunk of lines between `<<< & ===` or between `=== & >>>` while keeping the other chunk as is.

It'd probably help you get a better answer if you post the entire code between `<<< === >>>`